# PhoneGap AlertDialog List

Tags: android, list, cordova, android-alertdialog

Just getting started with PhoneGap and looking for a way to create the kind of dialog shown here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList
but only found notification.alert and notification.confirm - but there must be some way to create a list dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a <select/> box in your html. When you click on it that is the type of dialog box that will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Phonegap Android Plugin for this. When working with Phonegap Android plugin, you need to do:

1. Add the Java file in the /src folder
2. Update your /res/xml/config.xml for your Phonegap plugin settings
3. Call your the plugin with cordova.exec() in your HTML/Javascript

Do check the [Phonegap plugin development](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android) if you need extra guide on that.

You can download my [AlertDialog List](https://github.com/kidino/phonegap-alertdialoglist-plugin) plugin at github.

Assuming you have your Phonegap Android Eclipse setup properly, together with the plugin, in your HTML/Javascript, you can just call something like this.

```
<script>
var fruitlist = [
        "The Fruit List Title", // this is the title 
        "Orange", 
        "Apple", 
        "Watermelon", 
        "Papaya", 
        "Banana", 
        "Pear" 
    ];

function showlist(thelist) {
    cordova.exec(
        function(listitem) {
            alert( "You selected "+ thelist[listitem] );
        }, 
        function(error) {
            alert("Error Occured");
        }, "AlertList", "alertlist", thelist );
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:showlist(fruitlist)">Pick your fruit</a>
```

I think I should also remind you that you need to load `cordova` properly in your HTML/Javascript. We do that by listening to deviceready event. Otherwise, cordova.exec won't work. This is like the $(document).ready in jQuery.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", your_function, false);
```

**AlertDialog List Phonegap Android Plugin**

https://github.com/kidino/phonegap-alertdialoglist-plugin